# How can I perform multiple http request in Angular 2+ but wait for each to complete before doing the next?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have something similiar to this:

```
// Build requests array
const requests = [];
contacts.forEach(contact => {                     
  requests.push(
    this.httpService.post('/users', { name: contact.name })
  );
});

// Run them all at once and do stuff when they all complete
return Observable.forkJoin(requests).pipe(
  map(() => console.log('All requests are done!')),
  catchError(() => console.log('Something went wrong'))
);
```

Using `forkJoin` like this all http requests are made at once. How can I instead do the requests one by one? That is, I want request 1 to complete, THEN run request 2 etc. I couldn't find any rxjs operator that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `concat`. It'll subscribe to each source Observable one after another when the previous Observable completes.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

...

concat(...requests).pipe(
  toArray(), // Collect all responses to a single array
).subscribe((results) => ...);
```

Maybe you don't even use `toArray`, it depends on what you want to do with the responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap` for this type of http requests. Here is the piece of my code that can work for you.

```
public sendMailForExit(email) {
    email.employee.token = Common.newGuid();
    return this.http.postRequest(StaticKeywords.url_email + 'InitialSaveEmployeeExitDetails', email).map((response: Response) => {
      return response;
    })
      .flatMap((token: any) => {
        if (token.json().success === true) {
          email.employee.url = StaticKeywords.baseUrlApp + '#/' + StaticKeywords.url_employee + StaticKeywords.url_exitDetail +
            email.employee.ID + '/' + email.employee.token;
          return this.http.postRequest(StaticKeywords.url_email + 'sendEmail', email).map((innerResponse: Response) => {
            return this.CheckResponse(innerResponse);
          });
        } else {
          return [{ token: token }];
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for an **array of requests** as OP asked for.

Comment: yes you are right @HarunYılmaz , I misunderstood question